# Joi getting validationSchema: Joi.object() error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, joi

After installing `joi` on `nestjs` framework i'm trying to validate two property by `joi` something like:

```js
import Joi from 'joi';
...
ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    validationSchema: Joi.object(
        {
            PORT: Joi.number().required(),
            MONGODB_URI: Joi.string().required(),
        }
    )
}),
...
```

but i get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')
```

`main.ts`:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    // @ts-ignore
    app.useGlobalFilters(new ValidationPipe());
    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
    const port = configService.get<string>('PORT');
    await app.listen(port);
}
```

full error:

```
D:\develop\api\src\app.module.ts:16
            validationSchema: Joi.object(
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\develop\api\src\app.module.ts:16:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\develop\api\src\main.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
PS D:\develop\api>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Either use `import * as Joi from 'joi'` or set `esModuleInterop: true` in your `tsconfig.json`. Joi doesn't use a default export by default, so either a named/namespace import needs to be used (first option) or you need to tell Typescript to treat default and named imports similarly (second option)